# 100% height without content

Tags: html, css

Im having an (small) problem. Im trying to give my menu bar's background color, the same height as my main content div, So i thought Ill give the div an 100% height, but that doesnt seem to work since there is not more content to make the div's height higher, 
I have made an example, (made in jsfiddle) with my meaning. I know this is possible, since i've done this before. Its an kinda easy question, but you have those days that you littarly forget anything.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="boxLeft">
                menu1 </br>
                menu2 </br>
                menu3 </br>
            </div>  
            <div id="boxMid">
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
                Lorem ipsum <br />
            </div>
            <div id="boxRight">
            </div>              
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

​

```
*{color:white;}
#wrapper{height:100% width:100%;}
#boxLeft{float:left; width:100px; height:100%; background-color:gray;}
#boxMid {float:left; width:400px; height:100%; background-color:blue; }
#boxRight{float:left; width:200px; height:50px; background-color:orange;}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zEest/56/

Thanks for reading,

Comment: Try min-height:100% instead of height:100%

Comment: That doestn work, Ive littarly tried anything, lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at:

[Equal height columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

hope this help u. By the way you could use jquery to fix the height whem dom is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // event when DOM is ready.
  //sets the height of the boxes the same as the wrapper.
  $('#boxLeft, #boxRight').css('height',$('#wrapper').height());

});
```

To make your wrapper the correct height use the following:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="boxLeft">
            menu1 </br>
            menu2 </br>
            menu3 </br>
        </div>  
        <div id="boxMid">
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
            Lorem ipsum <br />
        </div>
        <div id="boxRight">
        </div>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>  
    </div>
```

With the css trick clear:both thre wrapper heights gets the max height of his children.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer a bit?

Comment: Thanks, This worked indeed, I didn't needed the clear: both, Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Just Add

```
body {  height: 100%;}
#wrapper{overflow:auto;}
```

***[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ifidez/2)***

As all the elements in the `#wrapper` element are floated so they are removed from normal flow. so to give height to the `#wrapper` add `{overflow:auto;}`

Comment: Thank you too! But this doesnt work in the website, also its not created by me, so i don't know the problems he made.

Comment: can you give us the weblink?

Comment: Can i send you an personal message?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using jQuery. simple two steps

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var midHeight = $('#boxMid').height();
   $('#boxLeft').height(midHeight);
});
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEest/87/)**

Give `widths` in percentages.. if you need those div's adjacent to each other.

Cheers :)

Comment: Oh dear, this doesnt seem to work perfectly, Are you still here?

Comment: @RinkeDoeser Its not clear what you mean by not working.. BTW, I updated my link.. I hope that is what you want...

Comment: I've used the script of patrick, That one worked, I don't know why yours didnt, but anwyays, it works now :)

Comment: @RinkeDoeser You haven't declared elements with ids `boxMid` and `boxLeft` and even you are not wrapping my given code in [`.Ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function, which is must.

Comment: Happy to know.. even I also recommend patrick's solution... nice and simple.. :)

Comment: Anyways, Thank you a lot my friend;)